# Is there any good dictionary web site for mobile web?

Tags: webapp-rec

When I want to look up a word in a dictionary I use the Google dictionary, it offers synonyms and examples, but it's not optimized for mobile web, so it's inconvenient to use.

Could you recommend a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [mobile version](http://m.dictionary.com/) of Dictionary.com

Comment: Good! What I wanted!